# How can you interpret the ratio of the coefficients travel time to the coefficient of travel cost

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

[image]

Just the e) question
This is the whole question, thank you all in advance.

Comment: It seems the teacher has problem.

Comment: Y'all don't know this is it possible